# signed distance between plane and point

Tags: math, vector

I cannot find a consistent method for finding the signed distance between a point and a plane. How can I calculate this given a plane defined as a point and a normal?

```
struct Plane
{
    Vec3 point;
    Vec3 normal;
}
```

Comment: why is dist = dotProduct(dif,dif)? distance should be: d(P, *B); ??

Comment: d(p,b) simply calls this = norm(sqrt(dot(p - b, p - b)));

Comment: So my code does the same thing.

Comment: How can it be negative with the sqrt in there?

Comment: Square root of a number can be positive or negative...

Comment: @ŽarkoTomičić In this case dot(a, a) >= 0 for all vectors in R^n. (Note that this question is 12 years old also).

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You're making things much too complicated. If your normal is normalized, you can just do this:

```
float dist = dotProduct(p.normal, (vectorSubtract(point, p.point)));
```

Comment: Sorry, but I couldn't figure out how the dot product could produce the distance between `p.normal` and `point - p.point`. Can you please explain(maybe using picture) that? In my case, `p.normal = (1, 0, 0)` and `point - p.point = (-200, 0, 0)`.

Comment: @user26409021: The idea is to find the signed distance between `point` and `p`. In your case, what do you think that is? I think it's -200.

Comment: Yeah, I know it give me the distance which `-200`.. So is it correct if I say by using `dotProduct`we could find distance between 2 points?

Comment: @user26409021: Yes, the distance between `p` and `q` is `sqrt((p-q).(p-q))`.

Comment: One explanation as to why this works is that you're computing a vector from an arbitrary point on the plane to the point; `d = point - p.point`. Then we're projecting `d` onto the normal. The projection formula is `p=dot(d,n)/||n||^2*n={n is unit}=dot(d,n)*n`. Since `n` is unit, the signed length of that vector is `dot(d,n)`.

Answer (score 4):

For those curious as to how the dot product formula posted by Beta is derived, here is a visual proof:

```
           N        Q
           ^        | 
           |        | d
           |        | 
           |        |
---------- P -------+------ > plane
```

d is the signed distance between Q and the plane

P is a known point that lies on the plane.

N is a normal unit vector perpendicular to the the plane at P.

To find d, we move d to where P and N are

```
           N
           ^
           |
           |
           +--------Q
           |      / 
         d |    /   
           |θ /     
           |/       
---------- P -------------- > plane
```

Use cosine to generate Equation 1

```
cos(θ) = adjacent / hypotenuse
cos(θ) = d / |PQ|                -- |PQ| is length of (Q-P)
     d = |PQ| x cos(θ)           -- Equation 1
```

Using the following dot product formula

```
a · b = |a| × |b| × cos(θ)
```

We derive Equation 2

```
    N . (Q-P) = |N| x |PQ| x cos(θ)
    N . (Q-P) = 1 x |PQ| x cos(θ)    -- |N| is 1 because unit vector
|PQ| x cos(θ) = N . (Q-P)            -- Equation 2
```

Substitute the left side of Equation 2 with Equation 1

```
d = N . (Q-P)
```