# Function for signed distance from a line/plane with a "front" vector?

Tags: math, line, distance, point, signed

I can't seem to find anything that can help me, it's either incomplete or it's full of math jargon that I don't quite understand (English is not my native language).

I have a line from l0 to l1, with front vector fv. I want the function to give me the distance of point p0 from the line, with a negative sign if p0 is at the "back" side of the line.

[image: What I want the function to calculate]

I have access to a complete Vector2 class if desired, the function can be in C++/C#/Java/JavaScript, I can translate it to C# myself.

Something like:
float Distance(Vector2 l0, Vector2 l1, Vector2 fv, Vector2 p0)

EDIT:
Turns out this will work for me: [signed distance between plane and point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3860206/signed-distance-between-plane-and-point)

Comment: It turns out that this answer works fine for me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3860206/signed-distance-between-plane-and-point

Answer (score 3):

Line equation is

```
(x-x0)/(x1-x0) = (y-y0)/(y1-y0)
```

Transform it to general form

```
a * x + b * y - c = 0
```

and find distance for point (px,py) as

```
Dist = Abs((a * px + b * py - c) / Sqrt(a^2 + b^2))
```

To determine what semiplane point p belongs to, find sign of dot product of vectors `(px-x0, py-y0)` and `(x1-x0, y1-y0)` and compare it with sign of `Dot(fv, (x1-x0, y1-y0))`

You can also find sign of cross product of `(px-x0, py-y0)` and `fv`

Another way for signed distance:

```
Dist = Dot((px-x0, py-y0), (x1-x0, y1-y0)) / Length(x1-x0, y1-y0)
```