# Point inside a 3d closed volume

Tags: c++, 3d, raycasting, point-in-polygon

I have a 3d closed volume defined by 6 surfaces, every surface has 4 vertices.

So, I want to check if a given point is inside the volume or outside it. A solution which I thought of was:

1. Draw a random line from the given point and check where it intersects the surfaces which enclose the volume. Since I am using vector algebra for calculating the intersection of the line and surface the intersection point can lie anywhere on the 3d infinite surface.
2. Now I check if this intersection point happens to lie on that face which lies on the infinite plane and encloses the volume.

For this I again want to draw a random ray from my point of intersection to the respective face of the volume and check if point lies on the face or not.

```
But I don't know how to check this feature of locating if it is on the surface  
or not. Can someone please suggest how can I do it.



P.S. One way of doing this was extending ray casting to 3d but that involves 
comparison of slopes to check the orientation. So how can I check orientation 
of 3 points in 3d space. I have 4 vertices which make up that face, I know the 
point under consideration. How can I check if this point lies clockwise or   
counter clockwise to the surface.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To consider your problem, we must first consider what the meaning of inside or outside is.  With a four surfaces solid, each surface divides the space in exactly two sides, and in general, the four surfaces divide the space in 9 regions, only one of which is bounded, delimiting a tetrahedron (but if we select carefully the surfaces we can reach to even no bounded region ---for example making two of them parallel).  So, in general you have to decide which of the sides of the planes mark the inside or the outside (well, it doesn't matter also, as being outside is the same as not being inside).

With more faces, the problem complicates (and complicates much further), as you can have several bounded regions that also define solids, so you need more information that only the planes that delimit it.  The problem even complicates more if the region results in a non convex region, because your point can be in some part of your region that matches the *in one side* for some planes and *in the wrong side* for others, and continue to be inside your solid.  Just see a delimited polygon like this

[image]

and the possibilities of making bounded regions

[image]

The first thing you need is to adequately define your solid, delimiting the faces with edges and somewhat establishing the edges and vertex that delimit one face, how faces connect themselves to form your solid.

Once you have this situation, you have a set of faces, and vectors pointing to the *outside* for each face (in a continous manner, so you don't end with a face normal pointing upwards, and the next pointing downwards).  The next thing you need to do is to divide your solid into a convex solid.  It can be demonstrated that for a 3d solid made of plain faces, it can be subdivided into a finite set of convex solids.

I will try to illustrate the same problem in 2D, but essentially is the same in 3D:

First, we have the initial poligon, let's suppose it is convex (this is an important property for this purpose I shall mention later):
[image]

Let's imagine it is a 3D asteroid and you are somebody walking on its surface.  If you begin walking, you'll pass through all the lines poined in yellow.  These are the normals and for that you need to know from each face which faces are reachable and construct a map of normals to these surfaces as I have made.  As you walk on the asteroid, you mark the normals to know where the interior of the asteroid is, and you are delimiting it.  Now, we have a map of our asteroid with all the normals.  Let's draw the semispace below us (one side of the surface that is below us)  In geometry, this can be represented by a plane (a plane has the property that all its points are orthogonal to a vector, so `X*V=0` where `*` represents the dot product.  If we take the center of our poligon and the normal vector as the yellow vector in our drawing, we'll get `(X - P)*N = 0`, where `X` is the position of a point in the plane, `P` is our position (the center of the face) and `N` is a vector normal to the plane, pointing upwards (to the outside of the asteroid)

Well, this equation has the property that if we substitute `X` by any position in the space, all the points `X` below the plane have a value `(X - P)*N < 0` and all the sky values have it `> 0`.

If I do the same for the four normals, I get to this:
[image: First plane]
...
[image: Fourth plane]
dealing to
[image]
and the point in question `X` will be buried into the asteroid only if the four planes give `(X - X_face)*(N_face) < 0` where now, `X_face` is the center of the face, and `N_face` is the face normal pointing outwards of our asteroid.  The point will be inside the asteroid **only** if the four conditions apply.

But what happens if the asteroid is not convex?

[image]

If you draw the normals, this will not help... as there are points that are inside the asteroid and fail some of the tests (remember, the point has to be below all the surfaces, but isn't (as shown below):

[image]

The problem is that the polygon (or the polyhedron) is not convex, and we cannot apply the algorithm there.  So first we have to solve the problem of making it convex.

If you begin to follow all the surface of the asteroid (conserving the normals) when you cross an edge, you'll get to another plane that increases or decreases slope, so if it increases slope, you will mark that edge (vertex in our polygon) as anomalous (we have marked them in red) and if it decreases, we'll mark them as normal (we have marked them in green):

[image]

When all edges are normal, no problem, as our asteroid will be convex, but when any of them is anomalous, we have to continue in that plane (digging in the asteroid on all the plane) until we get to another surface (we have prolonged the plane up to divide our poligon) as such:

[image: digging to divide the polygon into convex parts]

as we have a finite number of edges, and only some of them have been marked as anomalous, this process is warranted to finish (remember that you can get *the other side* trying to find a face (side) of your polyhedron (polygon) that has vertex up and vertex down (in the sense we explained before))

so you have divided your polyhedron into a finite set of convex polyhedra that can be applied the first algorithm.

[image: conversion of a polygon into a finite set of convex polygons]

Answer (score 3):

You could create a boolean condition for each surface that determines whether a given point is inside or outside the surface. This might require that you add information about the normals of each surface (i.e. which side of the surface is 'outwards'). If this condition holds for each of the six surfaces, then the point is inside the volume.

Another similar way to think of this is to create a system of linear inequalities using each surface to create one inequality, to create an enclosed space representing your volume. That also comes down to satisfying whether the point is 'inside' or 'outside' each surface, and checking whether the point is inside all surfaces.

Comment: I agree to this solution, but what I was looking for was a general algorithm which does not involves much of linear algebra and can be implemented the way ray casting is implemented in 2d.

Comment: @AnkitMishra How does ray casting not involve linear algebra?

Comment: Yes it does but it does it in a very simple way, it calculates the slope of points (P0,P1) and (P1,P2) and concludes if it is clockwise or counter clockwise. So, that's why I was trying to do, compare the slope and see if the orientation of two points on the line are different w.r.t the lines forming the surface then that line intersects the segment. But I am not sure how can I do this in 3d space

Comment: @AnkitMishra, ray casting is always made on the assumption that polyhedra are convex, so that solution is not as general as you think.  Look to my answer to get an idea of the complexity of a general polyhedra without the convex property (sorry, It was explained for a 2D polygon by obvious reasons)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this question: [signed distance between plane and point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3860206/signed-distance-between-plane-and-point)

Now, you just need to check if your point is on the right side (correct sign) of each of your volume surfaces. Something like this:

```
bool isInside(const std::vector<Planes>& planes, const Point& point){

  for(const auto& plane : planes){
    const auto dist = 
       dotProduct(plane.normal, vectorSubtract(point, plane.point));
    if(dist>0) return false;
  }

  return true;
};
```

Comment: I agree to this method, but it will give me the distance between point and and the infinite plane which I know is zero since I calculated the intersection. But I want to check if the point lies on the finite surface which is being made by four sets of points which I know. How can I do this? The signed distance is distance between the infinite plane and the point.

Comment: Well, the sides on each of the planes will always be the crossings of other planes. You only need to consider each surface as infinite. If the point would be outside of an edge, it means the other side of some of the other (infinite) surfaces. Think about the 2d case: You can check if a point is within the square at x=a,b y=c,d ,(that is: a<x<b, c<y<d) by checking that x>a, x<b, y>c, y<d.
The distance between your point and all the planes can not be zero, or you have a zero sized shape.

Comment: So, here is what I understand, if I find out the intersection of the 3d line and plane and then check whether it lies within the four vertices which form the face by doing this. Let P(x,y,z) be the point of intersection of line and plane and then if it lies in the cuboid which is formed by the extremities of the surface i.e. xlow, xhigh, ylow, yhigh, zlow, zhigh. Will this prove that the point is on the face. I think it should, just want an opinion.

Comment: I'm not following. What I suggest is that you first state each of the surfaces as a normal and a point, then follow my answer. You really can't do things like this without some linear algebra, like scalar products (projections).

Comment: Yes, I am sorry I was not clear. I am doing the same thing, define a plane by a normal and a point, i.e (p-p0).n where p is a variable point on the plane and p0 is a point on the plane which I know, n is the normal to the plane. Then define a line as p = d.l + l0 where d is a scalar and l is a vector in the direction of the line and l0 is a point on the line and check for intersection of this line and the plane. If this intersection lies in the region defined by the extremities of the face the point is on the face. And this gives a valid intersection of ray and the face. Is this ok?

Comment: @AnkitMishra, not sure. Sounds plausible - would have to draw it and consider what cases it could miss, if any. Try both methods and compare with some simple cases, profile if you need to make it fast.

Answer (score 0):

So, one way I think I can do this is:

Extend ray casting to 3d surface but that involves how may times a ray from the point under consideration crossed the volume. This involves finding the point of intersection of lines and the faces of the volume.

```
So what I can do is for a single face (and I will extend it to all the faces)
is, I check for the point of intersection of 3d line and plane by doing simple
algebra and then check if the point lies inside the cuboid formed by 
extremities of the vertices forming the face. i.e check if P(x.y,z) which is 
the point of intersection of line and plane lies inside the region defined by
extremities of the surface.
i.e.

x > xlow and x < xhigh and y > ylow and y < yhigh and z > zlow and z < zhigh.

These two conditions i.e. ray intersects the 3d plane and the intersection
lies in this region proves that the intersection of ray and plane lies on the 
surface which encloses the volume.


I can count the number of such intersections if it is odd, the point
lies inside the volume if it is even the point lies outside the volume.


Does anyone see a problem with this algorithm?
```